# mysql Query: Select Lastest Where Another Row With N doesn't exist

Tags: sql, mysql

sorry about the title, I'm not sure how to even describe this, which makes it even harder to search for a solution.

I have a table which has many answers:

```
CREATE TABLE `answers` (
  `a_id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `p_id` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
  `q_id` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
  `correct` int(1) NOT NULL default '0',
  `timestamp` timestamp NOT NULL default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`a_id`)
) ;
```

I need to select a `q_id` from a specific `user_id` and `p_id` where correct = 0, but only where a more recent row from the same user_id and p_id's `correct` field is not 1.

I can group by id, but am unsure how to eliminate groups where the top correct != 0

Thanks in advance. I've found many helpful answers here and am looking forward to contributing where I can.

**EDIT: Currently the query as stands, but takes 6 secs to execute:**

From both your answers I have query that works, but takes 6 secs to execute!

```
SELECT a.q_id FROM answers a    
JOIN (SELECT b.q_id, MAX(b.a_id) as a_id, b.correct
        FROM answers b  
       WHERE b.correct = 1 
         AND b.user_id = 1 
         AND b.p_id = 22
    GROUP BY b.q_id) c ON a.q_id = c.q_id 
                      AND a.a_id > c.a_id
WHERE a.correct = 0 
  AND a.user_id = 1 
  AND a.p_id = 22  
LIMIT 1
```

With no JOIN they take .26 secs. and .45 secs to execute How can I make it more efficient?

Is there another way to select the most recent correct = 0 row where a prev correct = 1 row does not exist?

Thanks for all your help!

Comment: @robr: What about the correct != 1/correct != 0 criteria, and the timestamp relationship between those records...

Comment: Could an old row be updated and should that be assumed a recent row?

Comment: ACK. I suspect query gets me no where. Nirmal I'm trying to implement yours now. Sorry OMG, your query is way over my head!

Comment: @robr: See my updated answer - it's relatively minor changes, but they make the query more accommodating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This query seems to be working best. It's my edited answer, updated with ordering the a.a_id and limiting the return to one.

```
  SELECT a.q_id 
      FROM user_q_answers a    
      JOIN (SELECT b.user_id,
                   b.popling_id, 
             b.q_id,
                   MAX(b.a_id) as a_id
              FROM user_q_answers b  
             WHERE b.correct = 1 
          GROUP BY b.q_id, b.user_id) c ON a.q_id = c.q_id
                                       AND a.user_id = c.user_id
                                       AND a.a_id > c.a_id
     WHERE a.correct = 0 
       AND a.user_id = 101
       AND a.popling_id = 170  
    ORDER BY a.a_id DESC
    LIMIT 1
```

Thanks very much to OMG Ponies and Nirmal for helping me through this. Sorry if answering my own question is bad form here, but I comprised my query based on what I learned from you both.

Thanks again!!!

Answer (score 0):

use the timestamp  infomation to get the latest. You can order the records according to the time.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have an auto increment field `a_id`, you can use it to find the latest entry. Timestamp calculations are slower than primary key sorting.

```
SELECT a.a_id, a.q_id, a.user_id, a.p_id, a.correct, c.correct
    FROM answers a 
    JOIN (SELECT b.p_id, b.user_id, b.correct
              FROM answers b 
              ORDER BY a_id DESC
              LIMIT 1) c
        ON (a.p_id = c.p_id
        AND a.user_id = c.user_id)
    WHERE c.correct != '1' 
    AND a.correct = '0'
    AND a.user_id = '1234'
    AND a.p_id = '5678'
    ORDER BY a.a_id DESC
    LIMIT 1;
```

If you don't want to limit the number of results, remove the last two lines of code.

Comment: If I want to specify user_id and p_id as hard coded value, would those go after and a.correct = '0' line, then the joined queries reference them? Also it looks ike ORDER BY a_id DESC needs an alias: b.a_id. Still I get the error 'Every derived table must have its own alias' Thanks tons for your help!

Comment: Looked like I missed a lot of columns in select statement and an alias for a derived table. I have corrected my answer. You can try and let me know.

Comment: Yes. You must specify them after `a.correct = '0'`. I have added in my answer. You can check them.

Comment: @Nirmal: Aside from the timestamp column being a date data type, everything else is integer - why're you using SQL string notation, using single quotes, for your comparison on correct, user_id, etc?!

Comment: Your subquery is only going to return one row, unrelated to your where clause.

Comment: From both your answers I have query that works, but takes 6 secs to execute!

SELECT a.q_id FROM answers a
 JOIN (
  SELECT b.q_id, MAX(b.a_id) as a_id, b.correct
  FROM answers b
  WHERE  b.correct = 1 AND b.user_id = 1 AND b.p_id = 22
  GROUP BY b.q_id ) c
    
 ON (a.q_id = c.q_id AND a.a_id > c.a_id)
WHERE  a.correct = 0 AND a.user_id = 1 AND a.p_id = 22 
LIMIT 1

With no JOIN they take .26 secs. and .45 secs to execute How can I make it more efficient?

Is there another way to select the most recent correct = 0 row where a prev correct = 1 row does not exist?

Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 0):

This is the method that I almost always use in these situations. It's ANSI compliant and in MS SQL Server the performance is typically much better than using subqueries. I can't speak to performance in MySQL though:

```
SELECT
     A1.q_id
FROM
     Answers A1
LEFT OUTER JOIN Answers A2 ON
     A2.p_id = A1.p_id AND
     A2.user_id = A1.user_id AND
     A2.timestamp > A1.timestamp AND
     A2.correct = 1
WHERE
     A1.p_id = 22 AND
     A1.user_id = 1 AND
     A1.correct = 0
     A2.a_id IS NULL   -- This can only happen if no rows were found matching the JOIN criteria
```

BTW, if you want "latest" then you should be looking at the timestamp and not the a_id. Although it might almost always be the case (when inserting at least) that the numbers are sequential based on time inserted, it's usually not guaranteed. This is absolutely the case in MS SQL and I'm pretty sure that it's true in MySQL as well due to transactions and potential rollbacks affecting the IDs.

Comment: Thanks Tom H. I'll look further into this query and the timestamp issue. I was ordering by auto increment based on a comment that it was faster than timestamps.